# Functional JavaScript, function returns bool on condition mapping array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I need to push to the array cities if there is no such a city

```
getCityList() {
    const { StoreInfo } = this.props;
    this.emptyCityList();
    return StoreInfo.map((StoreInfo, index) => {
        console.log(this.cityPushCheck(StoreInfo.city));
        if (this.cityPushCheck(StoreInfo.city)) {
            CITY_LIST.push({
                id: index, label: StoreInfo.city, value: StoreInfo.city, disabled: false
            });
        }
    });
}

cityPushCheck(city) {
    const MAP = CITY_LIST.map((CITY_LIST) => {
        if (CITY_LIST.label === city) {
            console.log('are equal');
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

I was trying `return CITY_LIST.map((CITY_LIST) =>`

without ***const*** or ***return*** `CITY_LITS.map` is not working 
can't get it.
what I am doing wrong?

**[UPDATE]**
So this solution worked for me

```
getCityList() {
    const { StoreInfo } = this.props;
    this.emptyCityList();
    return StoreInfo.map((StoreInfo, index) => {
        if (this.cityPushCheck(StoreInfo.city)) {
            CITY_LIST.push({
                id: index, label: StoreInfo.city, value: StoreInfo.city, disabled: false
            });
        }
    });
}

cityPushCheck(cityLabel) {
    const cityFromList = CITY_LIST.find(city => city.label === cityLabel);
    return cityFromList === undefined;
}
```

thanks to [@quittle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554990/quittle)

Comment: where is your array cities  ?

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. You seem to just want a normal loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking for exactly but I believe your question is how to implement `cityPushCheck` so that it returns `false` if the city is in `CITY_LIST` and `true` otherwise. Assuming `CITY_LIST` is an Array, there's a helpful function called [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on arrays that greedily check for the presence of an entry based on a condition.

```js
cityPushCheck(cityLabel) {
    // Grabs the instance of the city from the list if it was present
    const cityFromList = CITY_LIST.find(city => city.label === cityLabel);
    // cityFromList will be undefined if "find" didn't have a match
    return cityFromList === undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thank you worked just fine. maybe you can advise some modern js book or resource.

Comment: I personally find the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) to have a lot of good resources and easy to read docs. They also have a number of tutorials to help wrap your head around how to do common tasks in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

While use map, you go city by city in your array, and for each return boolean. You might consider use filter, and then check if the filtered array have any length just once

---

```
   cityPushCheck(city) {
    CITY_LIST.filter(CITY => CITY.label == city).length
 }
```

---

Now, if there isn't such city at array, length is 0 what is equal to false at JS